# is there a functionality in Python(using ctypes) to deal with vectors contained in c++ structures?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am writing a Python class using ctypes to mimic a c++ structure, Need help with resolving the std::vector<> defined in the c++ structure.

I've dealt with the general variables declared in the c++ structure of type uint64_t, double, long, char ,etc by declaring them as c_'type' in the *fields* declaration, But I'm unable to find a way to resolve the vector.

C++

```
struct TypeSample
{
 double _a
 double _b
 std::string toString() const
 {....}
}
struct Sample
{ 
    Sample()
    :
     _variableA(0),
     _variableB(1)
    {
    }
    uint64_t _variableA;
    double _variableB;
    std::vector<TypeSample> _variableC;
};
```

Python

```
from ctypes import *
class Sample(Structure):
  _fields_ = [('_variableA',c_unit64),
              ('_variableB',c_double),
              ('_variableC',?????????),
             ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for taking the time

Comment: ctypes deals with C, not sure  that C++ data types are available.

Comment: I think you'll need to look at cython or pybind11 for C++ classes like std::vector.

Comment: `ctypes` is the wrong tool if you need to use C++.  `ctypes` gives access to C interfaces.

Comment: I know, but my requirement is such that I need to work with it. Is there a way I could resolve it to an array and then use it? I just need the python script to communicate with the C++ script.

Comment: Can you change the C++ code?  You have to add an `extern "C"` interface that uses C data types.  It can be in another DLL if you don't have access to the C++ source of the DLL you are trying to call.  There are tools such as [SWIG](http://swig.org) that can generate a Python interface for a C++ DLL...no ctypes required.

Comment: You can simulate a vector by creating a pointer of voids (or your ctype struct). It will be easier for you to deal with in python.
Inside your `.dll` or `.so` you could work with a pointer of your structure.
An other option (not very optimised at ALL), but you could convert your `_variableC` each time you jump from python (list of ctype struct) to cpp (vector of struct)  and cpp (vector of struct) to python (list of ctype struct)